# uWSGIをpython3.6で使用したい

Tags: python, python3, nginx, pyenv, uwsgi

webサーバーにnginxを、アプリケーション部分にflaskを使用してアプリケーションを作ろうと思っており、uWSGIを利用することにしました。

下記サイトを参考に進めていたのですが、
`Milestone #4` のuWSGIの起動のところでエラーが発生してしまいます。
https://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/

エラー内容は、uWSGIのログを確認したところ下記内容でした。
python version:2.7.14と記載があるのですが、pyenvを使ってpythonのバージョンは3.6にしているため、パスがおかしいことが問題かと思っていますが、中々解消されません。
何かアドバイスをいただけますでしょうか。

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Tue Oct 23 14:06:13 2018] ***
・・・一部省略・・・
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3860
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/ec2-user/***/***/***_uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.14 (default, May  2 2018, 18:31:34)  [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
Set PythonHome to /home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/
ImportError: No module named site
```

参考情報

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0
```

~/.bash_profile中身

```
#export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
export PYTHONHOME="$PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6"
export PYTHONPATH="$PYENV_ROOT/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6"
```

~/.bashrc

```
# User specific aliases and functions
PYTHONPATH=:/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/
#PYTHONPATH=/home/ec2-user/***/***
```

***_uwsgi.ini

```
・・一部省略・・
home = /home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/
#pythonpath = ~/.pyenv/shims/python3.6
pythonpath = /home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6
・・一部省略・・
```

Answer (score 1):

参照されたサイトは、システム上のPython2を使ってvirtualenv環境を作成して、仮想環境内のpipを使ってuwsgiなどをインストールしているようです。kuunosuke さんはpyenvで3.6をインストールしてそれを使いたいそうなので、参考サイトのとおりにやるのと違う手順になるかと思います。

uwsgiのログにpython version:2.7.14と表示されているのは、virtualenv環境を作成時に、pyenvでインストールしたpython3.6からではなく、システム上のpython2を使って仮想環境を作成したのではないでしょうか？

python3.6で同じようにやるとしたら、

`virtualenv venv`

としているところを

`virtualenv -p /home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/python venv`

として、システムpython2ではなく、作成したpyenvの3.6をベースに仮想環境を作成することを明示したら良いと思います。（もしくは3.6にはvirtualenv相当のvenvが標準ライブラリにあるのでそれを使っても良いです。`/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/python -m venv venv`）

PYTHONPATHの設定などは自分で環境変数を設定するのではなくvirtualenvに任せるようにし、activateした仮想環境で `pip install`するようにすれば参考サイトと同じようにできると思います。
activateされた上では(venv)とプロンプトに表示されますのでそれを確認して正しくライブラリをインストールすると良いと思います。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。すみません、記載漏れだったのですが、今回仮想環境を作成せずに実施していました（virtualenv部分はスキップしていました）。そのため、サーバーに直接python3.6をpyenv経由でインストールし、その環境でuwsgi等をインストールしていました。教えていただいた方法も試してみた結果、(venv)とプロンプトに表示されることも確認出来たのですが、ログを確認するとやはりpython2.7.14となっていました。何か他に考えられる原因はありますでしょうか・・・。

Comment: そうすると参考サイトの手順とは違いますね。pipでuwsgiを入れたんですよね。その時のpipは

Comment: その時のpipはpyenv上のpython3.6のpipでしたでしょうか？
`pip --version`の実行結果が上記python3.6のpipかどうか、
`pip list`での実行結果にuwsgiが入っているでしょうか。

Comment: 返信遅れてしまいすみません。pip バージョンはpython3.6でした。また、pip listを確認したところuWSGIは入っていました。ログを見ていてpythonのバージョンについては変わらないのですが、他部分のログが少し変化してきて、どうやら起動はできているもののすぐに落ちてしまっていることがわかってきました。一度pythonのバージョンではなく、サーバーのメモリ等確認してみたいと思います！色々と参考になりました。ありがとうございました！